# Return multiple data types from a single ColdFusion REST endpoint?

Tags: rest, coldfusion

I'm trying to setup a ColdFUsion REST endpoint that can return a file in any number of formats *and* can return standard error messages but have been running into issues getting that working.  For example, a user should be able to send a GET request such as:

```
https://foo.com/rest/files/123?format=pdf
```

This would return the file with id `123` in pdf format.  And, if the user changed `format` to `txt` the same endpoint would return the file in text format.  *And*, if there is no file with id `123`, the endpoint would return a 404 error.

The problems I'm running into are twofold:

1. ColdFusion doesn't seem to give me a way to specify the mime or content type of the file I'm returning and is falling back to whatever is sent in the `Accept` header sent by the client.  This is especially a problem if the client doesn't send that header.
2. If the client sends an `Accept` header of `application/pdf`, I can't get CF to return any error other than a `500` and that's coming from CF, not from me.

The code for my endpoint handler is like this:

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="/files/{fileId}" produces="application/json,text/html,application/pdf">
    <cffunction name="getFile" access="remote" returnType="any" httpMethod="get">
        <!--- query database for file details --->
        <cfif qry.RecordCount eq 0>
            <cfreturn "404 Not Found" />
        <cfelse>
            <cfset fileBinary = fileReadBinary(qry.filePath) />
            <cfreturn fileBinary />
        </cfif>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does using `cfheader` to set the `Content-Type` not work? I don't believe `Accept` forces your server to do anything. Since in your code you aren't explicitly setting it, CF probably does the content negotiation for you, but if you include a `cfheader` you should be able to send whatever you want.

Comment: @Leeish, thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, with REST, `cfheader` does not seem to override whatever other mechanism CF is using to decide what `content-type` to return.

Comment: Is this all the code or are you working in a framework or platform or something. Are you setting things in your app.cfc